# How do I print an InDesign spread on one page?

Tags: adobe-indesign

How do I go about printing my InDesign spread as one page?

Comment: You wont get many views on this with that subject.  Suggest revising.

Answer (score 2):

In the print dialog, under *General* there is a check box that says *Spreads*. Make sure it's checked and you're in business.